# A gap in 360 degree canvas arc

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Why there is a gap in 360 degree arc

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100, 100);
ctx.arc(100, 100, 100, 90 * Math.PI / 180, 450 * Math.PI / 180);
```

and arc from 0 to 360 have not

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(310, 100);
ctx.arc(310, 100, 100, 0 * Math.PI / 180, 360 * Math.PI / 180);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YMtdZ/4/
It's a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome has several issues with the arc method for canvas.

You can solve this issue in Chrome by nudging the angle a little like this:

```
ctx.arc(100, 100, 100, 90 * Math.PI / 180.01, 450 * Math.PI / 180.01);
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/YMtdZ/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, merely an antialiasing quirk. Chrome seems to be *way* too precise with its antialiasing, and thus a small gap appears in some cases.

It's not happening on FF and IE10.